# Django "lazy query execution" principle

Tags: django, database

What would be the main problem if Django did not use "lazy query execution" principle?

```
 q = Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="What")
 q = q.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.date.today())
 q = q.exclude(body_text__icontains="food")
 print(q)
```

while print(q) executes then it hit the database.

Answer (score 2):

A several problems can be happen,

- If django hits by `q = Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="What")` then, it must need to store the QueryDict into q. For that simple reason it cam comes with big issues like datatypes, memory, time complexity bla bla bla :(
- After that you din't get that awesome feature `q.filter(.....)`. Because at the time there was already value So, it's not a possible architecture. But now it's storing objects and also the variable is acting like an objects.